# RavenDB trouble adding wherein to spatial intersect query

Tags: ravendb, spatial

I have an object **Partner** that looks like this:

```
public class Partner
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    public string ServiceKeyIds { get; set; }

    public double WorkingRadius { get; set; }

    public float Rating { get; set; }
}
```

I then have a projection **LocalPartner** that looks like this:

```
public class LocalPartner : Partner
{
    public string WorkingRadiusShape { get; set; }
}
```

My index **PartnersByLocation** looks like this:

```
public class PartnersByLocation : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Partner,LocalPartner>
{
    public PartnersByLocation()
    {
        Map = partners => from doc in partners
                            where doc.ServiceKeyIds != null
                            select new
                            {
                                doc.ServiceKeyIds,
                                WorkingRadiusShape = string.Format("Circle({0},{1}, d={2})", doc.Latitude, doc.Longitude, doc.WorkingRadius)
                            }.Boost((float)doc.Rating);

        Spatial(x => x.WorkingRadiusShape, options => options.Geography.Default());
        Index(x => x.ServiceKeyIds, FieldIndexing.NotAnalyzed);
    }
}
```

I try to query the index as follows:

```
public LocalPartnerList GetNearbyPartners(double lat, double lng, string serviceIds, double rad = 25, int page = 0, int resultsPerPage = 10)
    {
        RavenQueryStatistics stats;

        var point = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "POINT ({0} {1})", lng, lat);
        var query = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<LocalPartner, PartnersByLocation>().Statistics(out stats).Spatial(x => x.WorkingRadiusShape, c => c.Intersects(point));

        if (serviceIds != null && serviceIds.Any())
        {
            query = query.AndAlso().WhereIn("ServiceKeyIds", serviceIds.SafeSplit());
        }

        var raw = query.ToString();

        query = query.Skip(page * resultsPerPage).Take(resultsPerPage);

        var result = new LocalPartnerList();
        result.LocalPartners = query.SelectFields<LocalPartner>().ToList();
        result.Results = stats.TotalResults;
        result.Page = page;
        result.NumberPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)result.Results / (double)resultsPerPage);
        result.Radius = (int)rad;
        return result;
    }
```

This query works if I call the method and serciceIds is null. It returns the expected results, but as soon as I apply the .AndAlso().WhereIn() clause the query returns an empty set.

I am certain that there are matching records. I should note that the ServiceKeyIds property of Partner holds a string of comma-separated strings, and the serviceIds passed to the method is the same, and SafeSplit() is an extension method that returns an array of strings.

Comment: What does  the raw query looks like? Did you compare the service ids from the results without the IN to the results with the IN?

Comment: **Without the in** `SpatialField: WorkingRadiusShape QueryShape: POINT (12.5655 55.6759) Relation: Intersects`

**With the in** `@in<ServiceKeyIds>:(4126e5c5\\-44cd\\-4656\\-a12d\\-2a23b1e960f5) SpatialField: WorkingRadiusShape QueryShape: POINT (12.5655 55.6759) Relation: Intersects`

  _The first works, but not the second. Both throw an error if I copy the into the index viewer from the backend. The error reads "The field 'SpatialField' is not indexed". . ._

Comment: I found this comment _Note to the list, resolved on the call.
An issue with a resolved bug and using in for single item queries._ on [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/ravendb/wherein$20spatial/ravendb/hFvM7-eJc8c/iR3WzvoiL4MJ) thread. Do you remember what the bug was?

Comment: I think we didn't use In properly for this. Can you change your code so you would use compare instead of in for 1 item? Also, what build are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, Ayende. I'm using build 2851. Not sure how the compare should be. Are you thinking I should try .Contains()?

Comment: a) Upgrade to 2953. b) If this issue persists, if you have a single item, what happens when you using == instead of In for a single item?